# Trouble unpacking list in a customized way

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I'm trying to unpack some list which I've yielded within `get_item()` function. I know I can get desired result If I used `return` instead of `yield`.

I've tried:

```
def get_item():
    yield ["k","y","t"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_item():
        print(item)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
['k', 'y', 't']
```

Output I wanna get:

```
k
y
t
```

***What possible change should I bring about to get the desired result keeping `yield` as it is?***

Comment: keeping yield as it is? you mean not changing the `get_item` function?

Comment: Yes it is @Jean-François Fabre.

Comment: without changing the `get_item` function, you have no choice but iterating once more to get individual elements in an inner loop, as `yield` returns one element when iterated upon: the whole list. `yield from` is what you need instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Python 3.3, you can use `yield from`:

```
def get_item():
    yield from ["k","y","t"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_item():
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
k
y
t
```

[`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) is a new trick introduced in Python 3.3, a short part of it:

> For simple iterators, yield from iterable **is essentially just a shortened form of** for item in iterable: yield item:

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: [Python 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics) specifically, nice answer!

Comment: a little explanation as to why `yield from` worked would be very helpful @U10-Forward. Gonna accept it within minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Added some :-)

Answer (score 1):

Desired result you can get with `*` operator:

```
def get_item():
    yield ["k","y","t"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n'.join(*get_item()))
```

Prints:

```
k
y
t
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below:

```
def get_item():
    for _ in ["k","y","t"]:
        yield  _

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_item():
        print(item)
```