# Python3 - Count number of occurences of each pair between two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists, for example:

```
lst1 = [0, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2]
lst2 = [1, 3, 7, 9, 9, 11, 8, 3]
```

and I want to count, for elements at the same index, how many times they appear together, so the result should be something like a dictionary:

```
{ [0, 1] : 1,
  [2, 3] : 2,
  [4, 7] : 1,
  [5, 9] : 2,
  [6, 11] : 1,
  [5, 8] : 1 }
```

Is there a way to do this without looping, that would scale nicely? I need to run it for very large lists (~ 20k elements in each).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
Counter(zip(lst1, lst2))
```

Output:

```
Counter({(0, 1): 1, (2, 3): 2, (4, 7): 1, (5, 8): 1, (5, 9): 2, (6, 11): 1})
```

Comment: One just came in from somewhere

Comment: I added one just now

Comment: I guess everybody loves these concise collections/itertools/functools solutions

Comment: wut it's 9..... somtime you just get lucky, i got lucky [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351363/is-there-a-difference-between-boardx-y-and-boardxy-in-python/57351373#57351373)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Of course, just use the modules so we don't need to code them

Comment: I had the same few minutes later get a lot of upvotes thingy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985094/trouble-unpacking-list-in-a-customized-way/56985122#56985122

Comment: Mine is short too

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
>>> l = list(zip(lst1, lst2))
>>> {k: l.count(k) for k in l}
{(0, 1): 1, (2, 3): 2, (4, 7): 1, (5, 9): 2, (6, 11): 1, (5, 8): 1}
>>>
```